# Глючная пагинация в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
                        // запрос
                        $query = new WP_Query( [ 'category_name' => 'news' ] );
                        $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    ?>

                        <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                        <!-- пагинация -->

                        <!-- цикл -->
                        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                <div class="timeline__item">
                                    <div class="timeline__picture">
                                        <img src="<?php
                                        if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                            the_post_thumbnail_url();
                                        } else {
                                            echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/product-not-found.jpg';
                                        }
                                        ?>" class="timeline__thumb">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="timeline__theme">
                                        <h4 class="timeline__subtitle">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p class="timeline__description">
                                            <?php the_field('news_desc'); ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <span class="timeline__date">
                                                                <?php the_time('j F Y в H:i'); ?>
                                                            </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <!-- конец цикла -->

                        <!-- пагинация -->
                        <?php the_posts_pagination( array(
                                'paged' => $page
                            ) ); ?>

                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Нет постов по вашим критериям.' ); ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Здравствуйте! Имеется новостной сайт, вывожу на главную записи из соответствующей рубрики. В настройках чтения выставил отображение 4 записей, всего у меня их 7. Цикл отрабатывает норм, выводит 4 новости, пагинация the_posts_pagination (); тоже отрабатывает и даже меняет линки page/2/3/4 НО! на каждой из этих страничек посты отображаются одни и те же, в чем может быть проблема? Помогите пожалуйста, всю голову уже сломал

Comment: Для корректной работы Вам нужно получить номер текущей страницы посредством `get_query_var('paged')`, должно быть что-то вроде `$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` и добавить страницу в массив аргументов `'paged' => $page`. Ну и использование `query_posts()` -- плохая практика.

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/

Comment: Начни отсюда https://wpmag.ru/2014/query_posts-wordpress/

Comment: Да ребят я просто пробовал разные циклы, но у меня все равно не работает пагинация... Вот сейчас такой вот цикл...

Comment: @slavke в `WP_Query` текущую страницу тоже добавьте.